# Prove that $xRy \longleftrightarrow 7|(2x+5y)$ for all $x,y\in Z$ is an equivalence relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm trying to show that this relation is an equivalence relation.
$$xRy \longleftrightarrow  7|(2x+5y)  \text{ for all }  x,y\in Z$$
I need to show that $R$ is reflexive.  If I take every $x$ and $y$ are the same I can see that it's fine, how to write it in formal way?

For the next conditions I need some advice.

1. $(a,b) \in R \Rightarrow (b,a) \in R$, i.e., Symmetry
2. $(a,b) \in R , (a,c) \in R \Rightarrow (a,c)\in R$, i.e. Transitivity

Thanks!

Comment: I think you mean $R$ instead of $A$. There are parentheses missing in the definifion of $R$.

Comment: What is the universe, i.e. the set $\Omega$ such that $R \subseteq \Omega\times\Omega$? Is it $\mathbb{Z}$ or maybe $\mathbb{R}$ or yet something else?

Comment: Is your definition $xRy \longleftrightarrow  (\,\,\,7|(2x+5y)  \rightarrow x,y\in Z\,)$ or simply $xRy \longleftrightarrow  7|(2x+5y)$? I don't understand the '$\rightarrow x,y\in Z$' part. I'm assuming $R\subseteq \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @Alraxite I've edited the question to replace the three different uses of $\rightarrow$ as I thought was intended.  Apologies if I misinterpreted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For reflexivity, you need to show that $xRx$ for any $x\in\mathbb{Z}$. By your definition, $xRx$ if and only if $7$ divides $2x+5x=7x$; this is always true!

For the others, it really is just a matter of pushing through the definitions. For instance: for transitivity, suppose $xRy$ and $yRz$. We wish to show that $xRz$. By assumption, we must have $2x+5y=7k$ for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$, and $2y+5z=7h$ for some $h\in\mathbb{Z}$. Then 
$$
2x+5z=(7k-5y)+(7h-2y)=7k+7h-7y=7(k+h-y).
$$
Since $k+h-y\in\mathbb{Z}$, you've shown that $7$ divides $2x+5z$, and hence $xRz$.

Try finishing up with symmetry similarly.

Comment: why you set $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ why not both $\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Typo. :-)  One second.

Answer (score 3):

Symmetry:

$$(x,y)\in R\iff 7\mid(2x+5y)$$

Now, we have that

$$2y+5x=7(x+y)-(2x+5y) \implies 7\mid (2y+5x)\implies (y,x)\in R$$

Comment: Can you explain a little more? I didnt understand it.

Comment: How I can write the equivalence classes ( It's the right expression? ) $[x]_{R} = \{x \rightarrow 2|x\}$? its right?

Comment: The proof above shows symmetry: $\;(x,y)\in R\iff (y,x)\in R\;$...

Comment: how did you get to $7(x+y)-(2x+5y) \implies 7\mid (2y+5x)$? there is something with Symmetric difference? I dont understand it.

Comment: Look at the answer!:$$2y+5x=7(x+y)-(2x+5y)$$ so $\,2y+5x\;$ is the difference of two integers each divisible by seven so it itself is divisible by seven...

Comment: I was not able to find a solution alone,In addition take x and y and multiply by 7  and difference by the given its not obvious( its like a trick.. for me). thank you.

Comment: Oh, yes: of course it is a trick. There's nothing "obvious" or "immediate" here. You need to get used to try tricks like this in these cases.